# Determining coordinates in lat/lng of a point in pixels on a map after zoom has been applied

Tags: d3.js, zooming, geo

I'm trying to determine coordinates of point in pixels on a map using d3. The ultimate goal is determine which countries are currently visible on the map.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
method: function() {
    var e = $("#" + this.getView().getId());
    if (!e || e.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    this.width = e.width();
    this.height = e.height();

    this.topojson = window.topojson;
    var width = this.width;
    var height = this.height;
    var centered;
    var d3v3 = window.d3v3;

    var projection = d3v3.geo.mercator()
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

    var path = d3v3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);

    var svg = d3v3.select("#" + this.byId("map").getId());

    svg.selectAll("g").remove();

    svg
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "background")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .on("click", clicked);

    var g = svg.append("g");

    d3v3.json(getPath("/110m_admin_0.json"), function(us) {
          g.append("g")
              .attr("id", "states")
              .attr("class", "counties")
            .selectAll("path")
              .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects["110m_admin_0_"]).features)
            .enter().append("path")
              .attr("d", path)
              .attr("class", function(d) { return "q"+(Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 0)) + "-9"; });
        });

    var zoom = d3v3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom",$.proxy(function() {
        var width1 = width/2;
        var height1 = height/2;
        var xt1 = d3v3.event.translate[0];
        var yt1 = d3v3.event.translate[1];
        var x = xt1;
        var y = yt1;
        x+=width1;
        y+=height1;
        var proj = projection.invert([x,y]);
        proj[0]*=-1;
        proj[1]*=-1;
        var closestCountry = this.closestCountry(proj);

        console.log(d3v3.event.scale + " | " + [x,y] + " | " + proj + " | " + closestCountry );

        g.attr("transform","translate("+
            d3v3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3v3.event.scale+")");
        g.selectAll("path")
            .attr("d", path.projection(projection));

    },this));

    svg.call(zoom);
}
```

This code works when the zoom level is 1, but fails as soon as the zoom level changes.

Here's a few variations I've tried.

1)

```
var x = d3v3.event.translate[0];
var y = d3v3.event.translate[1];
x+=width/2;
y+=height/2;
var proj = projection.invert([x,y]);
```

2)

```
var x = d3v3.event.translate[0]/d3v3.event.scale;
var y = d3v3.event.translate[1]/d3v3.event.scale;
x+=width/2;
y+=height/2;
var proj = projection.invert([x,y]);
```

3)

```
var x = d3v3.event.translate[0];
var y = d3v3.event.translate[1];
x+=width/2*d3v3.event.scale;
y+=height/2*d3v3.event.scale;
var proj = projection.invert([x,y]);
```

4)

```
var x = d3v3.event.translate[0]/d3v3.event.scale;
var y = d3v3.event.translate[1]/d3v3.event.scale;
x+=width/2*d3v3.event.scale;
y+=height/2*d3v3.event.scale;
var proj = projection.invert([x,y]);
```

One thing I have noticed is that whatever the zoom level, projection.invert() for the same [x,y] point (e.g. [1200,600])
always return the same lng/lat. Furthermore, none of the attempts I've made manage to keep [x,y] constant at varying zoom level so there is something else at play here outside of the translation and scale. I suspect it might have something to do with the projection, but I've still not figured out what.

Comment: You'll need to take into account the scale and translate as a result of the zoom, before doing the projection.invert()
.  You can retrieve both of these from the zoom object, so you should be able to divide by the scale and translate the reverse of the zoom's translate to convert back to the default pixel co-ordinates which can then be passed into projection.invert()

Comment: @BenLyall Thank you for the comment. I've edited my question based on your comment.

Comment: Now that I've had a bit more time to think and investigate, it may be possible for you to use the built in .translate() and .scale() methods of the projection to do the work for you.  You can take a look at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206340 and see if that works for you.  You should be able to update the projection's scale and translate from the zoom behavior and then use projection.invert() to get the lat/long back from a pixel location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After zoom has been applied, I haven't found a way to go from a point in pixel to a coordinate in lng/lat or from a point in pixel to a country.

That being said, I found an alternate method that works well too. I have a list of all the countries and their centroids in lng/lat. From that list, I resolve their position in pixel and adjust them based on scale and translation. Finally, I find which one is the closest to the center. Here's the code:

```
closest: function() {
    var p2 = [0,0];
    var d = [width/2,height/2];
    var scale = d3v3.event.scale;
    var translate = d3v3.event.translate;
    var min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    var minCountry = null;
    for ( var key in this.centroids) {
        var p1 = projection(this.centroids[key]);
        p1[0]*=scale;
        p1[1]*=scale;
        p1[0]+=translate[0]-d[0];
        p1[1]+=translate[1]-d[1];
        var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2[0] - p1[0],2) + Math.pow(p2[1] - p1[1],2));
        if (distance < min) {
            min = distance;
            minCountry = key;
        }
    }
    return [ minCountry, min ];
}
```